# Persistent Invisibility

Tags: dnd-3.5e, invisibility

If a persistent invisibility spell is cast upon a creature, and that creature attacked, would the spell end, be suppressed, or continue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A persistent [*invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#invisibility) spell ends if the subject attacks

The 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*invisibility*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#invisibility) [illus] (*Player's Handbook* 245) has the entry *Duration: 1 min./level (D).* (The parenthetical D is for [dismissible](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#dismissible); it's unimportant here.) Modifying this *invisibility* spell with the metamagic feat **Persistent Spell** (*Complete Arcane* 81) essentially changes this entry to *Duration: 24 hours (D).*

Elements of the *invisibility* spell besides its duration remain unchanged by the application of the feat Persistent Spell. Thus, still, "[t]he spell ends if the
subject attacks any creature" (*PH* 245).